# Accordion scroll to top issue with active section

Tags: jquery

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7csj8Lf/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function close_accordion_section() {
        $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
        $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
    }

    $('.accordion-section-title').click(function (e) {
        // Grab current anchor value
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

        if ($(e.target).is('.active')) {
            close_accordion_section();
        } else {
            close_accordion_section();

            // Add active class to section title
            $(this).addClass('active');
            // Open up the hidden content panel
            $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open').animate({
                scrollTop: -50
            });
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(".accordion .accordion-section-title:eq(0)").trigger('click');

    $('.accordion-section-title').bind('click', function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            theOffset = $(self).offset();
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: theOffset.top - 50
            });
        }, 300); // ensure the collapse animation is done
    });
});`
```

The scroll to top functionality seems to work fine in the fiddle, but doesnt work locally on my machine in my browser with the same code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any error? It's hard to help when you show us a functional code...

Comment: Thanks for the reply Karl

Yes the following error - my bad I should have added this:

ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable theOffset
 

ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable theOffset
theOffset = $(self).offset();

Comment: Try adding the keyword var before : `var theOffset = $(self).offset();`. But that shouldn't be a problem... Except if you use `'use strict'` but did not put it in your fiddle.

Comment: Hi Karl, excellent thanks very much. It works great, I should have declared it as a variable.